# Prolog reading the table in txt

Tags: file-io, prolog

I am having a problem of reading a text file that contains this information:

T11, R1, 6:00-18:00
T12, R1, 6:00-18:00
T13, R1, 18:00-6:00

For now I have a prolog code for reading it , if I add '' in each line and period in the end. It converts it to one List , but I need separate lists for each line. I also tried to 
use:

```
/*rows(Total,Rows_list):-
    atomic_list_concat(Rows_list,nl, Total),
    write(Rows_list), nl.*/
```

But it does not work and displays error message of too long string.

```
main :-
    open('taxi.txt', read, Str),
    read_file(Str,Lines),
    close(Str),
    write(Lines),
    nl.

read_file(Stream,[]) :-
    at_end_of_stream(Stream).

read_file(Stream,[X|L]) :-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),
    read(Stream,X),
    read_file(Stream,L).
/*rows(Total,Rows_list):-
    atomic_list_concat(Rows_list,nl, Total),
    write(Rows_list), nl.*/
```

Answer (score 2):

read/2 isn't appropriate to parse 'free text' files, because it's meant to parse *fully* structured Prolog terms, like those written by writeq/1, or listing/0.

Usually, the easier way to parse files is by use of a DCG. Since it's a parse of character by character, you will need some attention to details:

```
:- [library(dcg/basics)].

read_file(Stream,[]) :-
    at_end_of_stream(Stream).

read_file(Stream,[X|L]) :-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),
    read_line_to_codes(Stream, Codes),
    ( phrase(parse_record(Record), Codes) -> assertz(Record) ; writeln('ERROR')),
    read_file(Stream,L).

parse_record(taxi(T1, R1, (H1:M1)-(H2:M2),
       T2, R2, (H3:M3)-(H4:M4),
       T3, R3, (H5:M5)-(H6:M6))) -->
    parse_triple(T1,R1, (H1:M1)-(H2:M2)), " ",
    parse_triple(T2,R2, (H3:M3)-(H4:M4)), " ",
    parse_triple(T3,R3, (H5:M5)-(H6:M6)).

parse_triple(T,R, (H1:M1)-(H2:M2)) -->
    string(Ts), ", ", string(Rs), ", ",
    integer(H1), ":", integer(M1),
    "-", integer(H2), ":", integer(M2),
{atom_codes(T,Ts), atom_codes(R,Rs)}.
```

An useful feature of DCG is that can be tested fairly easily inlining data:

```
?- phrase(parse_record(R),"T11, R1, 6:00-18:00 T12, R1, 6:00-18:00 T13, R1, 18:00-6:00").
R = taxi('T11', 'R1', (6:0)- (18:0), 'T12', 'R1', (6:0)- (18:0), 'T13', 'R1', (18:0)- (6:0))
```

*edit* I definitely need more coffee, as I didn't noticed the list argument you passed to read_file. The code should read

```
read_file(Stream,[X|L]) :-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),
    read_line_to_codes(Stream, Codes),
    ( phrase(parse_record(X), Codes) -> true ; writeln('ERROR')),
    read_file(Stream,L).
```

Comment: but if I have many taxi data??? Ho do I handle for example T11, R1, 6:00-18:00, 6, 43.668943, -79.386211
T12, R1, 6:00-18:00, 3, 43.652946, -79.363219
T13, R1, 18:00-6:00, 3, 43.668943, -79.386211
T21, R2, 6:00-18:00, 4, 43.668943, -79.386211
T22, R2, 18:00-6:00, 3, 43.668943, -79.386211
T31, R3, 6:00-18:00, 3, 43.668943, -79.386211
T32, R3, 18:00-4:00, 3, 43.668943, -79.386211
T41, R4, 6:00-18:00, 5, 43.668943, -79.386211
T42, R4, 18:00-4:00, 3, 43.668943, -79.386211